# sqlalchemy: does relation.foreignKeys support for multiple list of foreignKeys?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy with flask app with PostgresDB
One of my tables has **multiple ForeignKeys** to same table **PrimaryKey**
Need to represent children and better in single query
Here is my table

```
class Codes(Model):
    __tablename__ = "codes"
    code_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code_name = Column(String, unique=True)
    with_1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    with_2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    with_3 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    child_1 = relationship("Codes", back_populates="code_1", foreign_keys=[with_1])
    child_2 = relationship("Codes", back_populates="code_2", foreign_keys=[with_2])
    child_3 = relationship("Codes", back_populates="code_3", foreign_keys=[with_3])
    code_1 = relationship(
        "Codes", back_populates="child_1", remote_side=[code_id], foreign_keys=[with_1]
    )
    code_2 = relationship(
        "Codes", back_populates="child_2", remote_side=[code_id], foreign_keys=[with_2]
    )
    code_3 = relationship(
        "Codes", back_populates="child_3", remote_side=[code_id], foreign_keys=[with_3]
    )
```

But it makes 3 queries for each child

My expectation use like next code

```
class Codes(Model):
    __tablename__ = "codes"
    code_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code_name = Column(String, unique=True)
    with_1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    with_2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    with_3 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("codes.code_id"))
    children = relationship("Codes", back_populates="parent", foreign_keys=[with_1,with_2,with_3])
    parent = relationship(
        "Codes", back_populates="children", remote_side=[code_id], foreign_keys=[with_1,with_2,with_3]
    )
```

But it raises next error: `Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list` which already provided

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[Codes(codes)]'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Codes.children - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Not sure what exactly is wrong here